# CENTOS 7 - Express app not listening on Public IP

Tags: centos

I am quite new to CENTOS. I have created a express application that listens to port 3001 on the server. The server is attached to a public IP. It works fine and I am able to access the HTML.

Now when I run the express app, there is not data that is reaching the express app, eventhough the port is listening.

please find below the result of  `netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "`

```
 tcp6       0      0 :::3001                 :::*                    LISTEN


 firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=3001/t
```

And this command shows success.

And my express app is running.

Answer (score 0):

From the `firewall-cmd` man page:

> `--permanent`
> The permanent option `--permanent` can be used to set options permanently. These changes are not effective immediately, only
> after service restart/reload or system reboot. Without the `--permanent`
> option, a change will only be part of the runtime configuration.
>
> If you want to make a change in runtime and permanent configuration,
> use the same call with and
> without the `--permanent` option.

Note the last line...

Comment: I tried this ... I rebooted the system .. It is still the same ...

Comment: Public IP : Port is not responding ... I can access the same sever with the PRIVATE IP : PORt and it works

Comment: I assume you can `ping` the public IP?  If you have access to another Linux machine on the same public network, you could try `nmap` scanning to see if the port is visible.  You could also temporarily flush the firewall to see if it works (but don't forget to re-instate it afterwards!)